# MDX Calculated Measure based on another calculated measure error

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I have a calculated member called [Ratio] in SSAS.  I would like to create a calculated member from that calculated measure but only see it for 2 members in the same level of a dimension.  How can I do that?  I have tried Exists, Aggregate, ect. with no success.

Also, any helpful links to learning MDX would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "see it for 2 members in the same level of a dimension"? Do you mean that for any member other than these 2, the value should be NULL?

Comment: For example, I have a states dimension and I want to see the ratio for 3 specific states (combined).  I don't want to see each state individually, only the combined value for the 3 states.